# Make problem with includes

Tags: centos, path, make

I am installing `imagick-v3.1.0RC2` package on CentOS 5.5. I have ImageMagick 6.7.9-9 installed as well and have a problem on the `make` step.

Problem is that its cannot find included file:

> /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick/accelerate.h:25:31: error: magick/morphology.h: No such file or directory

If I copy folder `magick` over into `/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick/magick`
then it will find it but will say some other file is missing in `magic/xxx.h` so I have to copy magick again and again there should be some way around?

I created a symlink in `/ImageMagick/wand/magick` `ln -s ../magick magick` however it still has the same problem inside file `accelerate.h` on line 25 it has  `#include <magick/random_.h>`

I also tried to do

```
make --include-dir=/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ --include-dir=/usr/local/include/ImageMagick` and `make -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick
```

I ended up running `make -n` to show all commands that make will execute and then added `-I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick` to them and run one by one manually.

Isn't there faster way?

**EDIT, SOLVED:**

The trick was to find where file is with `find / --name "missing.file"` and then add the symlinks in the folder where I run Make i.e. `/usr/src/imagick-v3.1.0RC2/`

```
ln -s usr/local/include/ImageMagick/magick magick
```

and

```
ln -s usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand wand
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding -I until the wand directory like `-I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand` or  `-I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick`

Comment: its the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you seem to misunderstand `make` completely. I'll assume we're talking about GNU make for this answer, although some people seem to outright deny the existence of alternative flavors.

What you achieve with these two lines:

```
make --include-dir=/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ --include-dir=/usr/local/include/ImageMagick
make -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick
```

is that you pass these parameters to `make`. Well, that's legal and all, but it gives the includes to be included into the `Makefile`/`GNUmakefile`, not the includes used by any compiler called by the `make` process.

In order to achieve that, the best is to run it as:

```
make -npf /dev/null
```

(pipe into `less` or so)

to get a feel for the default rules. Assuming you want the C or C++ compiler to find these files and assuming the make process uses the default rules and/or conventions, you should be able to set one of the following variables:

- `CPPFLAGS` (C preprocessor flags)
- `CFLAGS` (C compiler flags)
- `CXXFLAGS` (C++ compiler flags)

To see the exact details for *your* `make` file check out

```
make -np
# or ...
make -npf Makefile
```

in case default rules are re-defined.

Depending on the internals of the `make` process this will help to point the compiler to the right place. For example if GCC is used for compilation *and* linking `CPPFLAGS` should work fine. In you example you'd want to invoke `make` thus as:

```
make CPPFLAGS="-I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick"
```

assuming you don't just want to use the default target, but a target named `install` you'd do:

```
make CPPFLAGS="-I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick" install
```

... and another alternative is to pass the variable as environment variable to `make instead` of passing it on the command line:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ -I /usr/local/include/ImageMagick" make
```

... in a similar fashion you can set defines (`-DNAMEOFDEFINE=VALUE`).